# I have problem when i added New Scaffolded Item in razor page tutorial of doc.microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have problem when i added New Scaffolded Item in razor page tutorial of doc.microsoft
in [tutorial pages.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

**Step 4 Complete the Add Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD) dialog:**

I have error message:

> Finding the generator 'razorpage'...
> Running the generator 'razorpage'...
> Generating a new DbContext class 'RazorPagesMovie.Data.RazorPagesMovieContext'  > Attempting to compile the application in memory with the added DbContext.
> There was an error creating a DbContext :
> (10,19): error CS1001: Identifier expected
> (11,6): error CS1513: } expected
> (12,44): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
> (13,13): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
> (13,27): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
> (14,9): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
> (18,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
> (19,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected     > at `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.<BuildCommandLine>b__6_0()M:\ASP\WebApp\RazorPagesMovie\RazorPagesMovie\Startup.cs`
> (30,13): error CS8389: Omitting the type argument is not allowed in the current
> context
> at
> `Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)`
> at
> `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.Execute(String[] args)`
> at
> `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.CodeGenCommand.Execute(String[] args)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0qFR.png)

Comment: In the output window you can see it saying you are missing `}` at 11,6 line.

Comment: Please include the code as text as well as the error messages. Perhaps you're using a newer version of the scaffold than of the SDK or vice versa. Impossible to tell with the information presented here.